# How to save [String] to Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am trying to save the JSON response in the realm using Alamofire and ObjectMapper. And I am getting this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Index 0 is out of bounds (must be less than 0).'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001113e18db **exceptionPreprocess + 331
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110984ac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   Realm                               0x000000010e30efee _Z20RLMThrowResultsErrorP8NSString + 670
>       3   Realm                               0x000000010e310206 _ZL25translateRLMResultsErrorsIZ28-[RLMResults objectAtIndex:]E3$_6EDaOT_P8NSString + 118
>       4   Realm                               0x000000010e310136 -[RLMResults objectAtIndex:] + 102
>       5   RealmSwift                          0x000000010fa37436 $s10RealmSwift7ResultsCyxSicig + 262
>       6   App Name            0x000000010c0e9155 $s24Mahalaxmi_Life_Insurance12CalculatorVCC14collectionView_22numberOfItemsInSectionSiSo012UICollectionG0C_SitF + 197
>       7   App Name            0x000000010c0e934c $s24Mahalaxmi_Life_Insurance12CalculatorVCC14collectionView_22numberOfItemsInSectionSiSo012UICollectionG0C_SitFTo + 76
>       8   UIKitCore                           0x00000001155dd2c3 -[UICollectionViewData _updateItemCounts] + 409
>       9   UIKitCore                           0x00000001155dfb4f -[UICollectionViewData numberOfSections] + 22
>       10  UIKitCore                           0x00000001155eafbe -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _getSizingInfosWithExistingSizingDictionary:] + 511
>       11  UIKitCore                           0x00000001155ed228 -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _fetchItemsInfoForRect:] + 231
>       12  UIKitCore                           0x00000001155e5dc1 -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout prepareLayout] + 246
>       13  UIKitCore                           0x00000001155dd5a8 -[UICollectionViewData _prepareToLoadData] + 212
>       14  UIKitCore                           0x00000001155ddfb4 -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:] + 53
>       15  UIKitCore                           0x00000001155acec6 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 261
>       16  UIKitCore                           0x000000011620ae69 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1417
>       17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010de75d22 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 173
>       18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010de7a9fc _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 396
>       19  QuartzCore                          0x000000010de86d58 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 72
>       20  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ddf624a _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 328
>       21  QuartzCore                          0x000000010de2d606 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 610
>       22  UIKitCore                           0x0000000115d5399c _afterCACommitHandler + 245
>       23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001113482c7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23
>       24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011134278e __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
>       25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111342e01 __CFRunLoopRun + 1505
>       26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001113424d2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
>       27  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011971b2fe GSEventRunModal + 65
>       28  UIKitCore                           0x0000000115d2bfc2 UIApplicationMain + 140
>       29  App Name            0x000000010c0a976b main + 75
>       30  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011238e541 start + 1
>       31  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

JSON Response is  like this

```
["Title": [ "S", "Y", "H", "Q", "M" ]]
```

My Model is like this

```
class TermList : Object, Mappable {
    @objc dynamic var mainTerm : String?
    var payingTerm = [String]?

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        mainTerm <- map["MainTerm"]
        payingTerm <- map["PayingTerm"]
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sammy please check the console log in the description

Comment: The model is irrelevant because it cannot cause the crash. The crash (which is an *index-out-of-bounds* exception) is related to some collection view method.

Comment: Please share your ViewController's code.